Is it normal that Selenium gives me "NoSuchElementException" even if element.isdisplayed return me true
I am praticing Selenium following this tutorial working on this page. I am using the more recent version of Selenium (4.26), TestNG (7.10.2 and of Java JDK (Java 23) with IntellJ Community edition.
While I was following the tutorial I have noticing that a test continue to give me "No such element exception" when I launch this method:
private By uploadButton= By.xpath("//*[@id='file-submit']"); 

public void clickUploadButton(){
    WebElement button= driver.findElement(uploadButton);
    button.click();
}

Before to use the XPath, I've tried with id and class but nothing. I've even put an implicit way but nothing change.
The strange part is if I try to use "isDisplayed" method on the element before the click, it returns me true. So I don't understand why during the test this element results not found.
I put all the code and the answer here:
public void clickUploadButton(){
    WebElement button= driver.findElement(uploadButton);
    System.out.println("the element is "+button.isDisplayed());
    button.click();
}

SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
nov 12, 2024 10:34:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.devtools.CdpVersionFinder findNearestMatch
WARNING: Unable to find CDP implementation matching 130
nov 12, 2024 10:34:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver lambda$new$5
WARNING: Unable to find version of CDP to use for 130.0.6723.117. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.26.0` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.
the element is true

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".button"}
  (Session info: chrome=130.0.6723.117)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Build info: version: '4.26.0', revision: '8ccf0219d7'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '23'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [86364529612327c68c95c4fba0a9bb2c, findElement {using=class name, value=button}]
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 130.0.6723.117, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 130.0.6723.116 (6ac35f94ae3..., userDataDir: C:\Users\CARLOC~1\AppData\L...}, fedcm:accounts: true, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:52980}, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platformName: windows, proxy: Proxy(), se:cdp: ws://localhost:52980/devtoo..., se:cdpVersion: 130.0.6723.117, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:extension:credBlob: true, webauthn:extension:largeBlob: true, webauthn:extension:minPinLength: true, webauthn:extension:prf: true, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 86364529612327c68c95c4fba0a9bb2c


Are you sure that you are looking at the correct place? In your code you locate a button using By.xpath("//*[@id='file-submit']") but the error message tells you that it cannot locate an element by {"method":"css selector","selector":".button"}

I have a feeling we're not seeing the actual code that throws the error here.   In general the click() method would only throw null pointer, click intercepted, stale element, or element not interactable.   (there are a few others, but not "no such element"... findElement would throw that)

Try to click the button using JavaScriptExecutor. See code below:
WebElement button= driver.findElement(uploadButton);
//button.click();
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Imports:
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;

Note: Generally one should use JS as a last resort when Selenium is not able to perform the desired action.
